# Was bedeutet "sich einlassen"?

Tags: single-word-request

Dieser Satz kommt aus einem Strafbefehl:

*Ihre Angaben, soweit Sie sich eingelassen haben …*

In diesem Teil wurden verschiedene Beweismittel aufgelistet. Ich verstehe aber überhaupt nicht, was das Verb *sich einlassen* hier bedeutet.

Zuerst dachte ich mir: vielleicht hat der Mann keine Angaben gegeben, das würde also bedeuten: *falls Sie sie gegeben haben*. Dann aber dachte ich: *falls Sie darin einwilligen*?

Weiß jemand, worum es hier geht? Ich würde mich auch ungemein über eine polnische/englische/russische Übersetzung freuen.

Answer (score 3):

*Sich einlassen* bedeutet hier vereinfacht ausgedrückt, *die Angaben, die Sie hierzu gemacht haben*.

Eine Einlassung ist laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einlassung) "die Stellungnahme eines Beklagten im Zivilprozess zu gegen ihn erhobenen Ansprüchen oder eines Angeklagten im Strafprozess zu gegen ihn erhobenen Vorwürfen".

Eine weitere Übersetzung dieses juristischen Fachbegriffs in eine andere Sprache traue ich mir nicht zu.

Comment: Eine *Einlassung* ist nicht notwendigerweise an einen Gerichtsprozess gebunden. Auch das Stellungnehmen zu einem Strafbefehl (z.B. bei einer Ordnungswidrigkeit im Strassenverkehr) gilt als *Einlassung*. Wikipedia ist hier ein bißchen zu speziell.